# Variation on Simpsons Rule error

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I was messing around with proofing the error of Simpsons Rule and found a weird result. Let $c = \frac{a+b}{2}$

$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(x)dx &= \int_a^b f(c) + f'(c)(x-c)+\frac{1}{2}f''(c)(x-c)^3 + \frac{1}{6}f'''(\xi)
(x-c)^3dx \\\\
&= \left[ f(c)x + \frac{1}{2}f'(c)(x-c)^2 +\frac{1}{6}f''(c)(x-c)^3 + \frac{1}{24}f'''(\xi)
(x-c)^4 \right]_a^b \\\\
&= f(c)(b-a) + \frac{1}{24}f''(c)(b-a)^3
\end{align}
$$
It seems like this shouldn't work so I tried it for a random fourth degree polynomial and didn't work. Is there some rule I broke or a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Proofing means to make something tight, secure (perhaps from making provably reliable for some purpose). You prove a theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have successfully derived the error term for the midpoint quadrature rule.

For Simpson you need to combine two facts: The integral over $f$ is the same as the integral over $g(x)=\frac12(f(x)+f(a+b-x))$ which is even symmetric about $x=c$. And in the Newton-Hermite interpolation polynomial identity
$$
g(x)=f(c)+g[a,c](x-c)+g[a,c,b](x-a)(x-c)\\+g[a,c,c,b](x-a)(x-c)(x-b)\\+g[a,c,c,b,x](x-a)(x-c)^2(x-b)
$$
the second and fourth term are odd symmetric about $x=c$, so their integration gives zero. The last term becomes the error term of the quadrature using the mean value theorem as usual.